# Is a 700-23C 23/622 Road Bike Tire appropriate for a 25-28/622 Road Bike Wheel?

Tags: road-bike, tire, wheels, innertube

Simply Put, the tire bead won't hook into the wheel.  The issue occurs with BOTH Wheels.  I thought one rim might be compromised, but NOT both.  When inflating the wheels, the Tube starts to push through  between the Tire and  Wheel to produce an  external  bubble - I once exploded a tube since it was on the opposite side of the Wheel and NOT noticed...until too late.  It's a rather amazing sound indoors - neighbors thought I shot my wife.

The Wheel width in 15 mm and according to the Chart it "should" be OK with a tire width of 23-32 which I thought was the ISSUE.  Apparently NOT.

What's my Real Issue

[image: Wheel / Tire Fit]

Comment: Please mention brand of tyre and type thanks.

Comment: Has the rim been damaged by collision?  Is the tyre new?   If tyre is used, was it fitted to this rim in the past?  Does the tyre always come off at the same point around the rim?

Answer (score 3):

It is fine to mount a 23mm tire on your rim. First, a very minor bit of terminology: we don’t say “25-28c road wheel” as in the title. As you are aware, the rim’s inner width (distance between the bead hooks) is relevant in some cases.

This [video by Park Tools](https://youtu.be/eqR6nlZNeU8) shows the process of mounting a new tire and tube. One important step later in the vid is that you should check before inflation if the tube is pinched between the tire bead and the rim. Probably most of us have had this happen at some time early in our careers, and I know I did this at least twice before I learned to check before inflation. As a double safety measure, you can inflate to about 15-25 psi and then look at both sides of the wheel; at this pressure, a road tube would be visible if it were pinched, but this is low enough that it won’t blow. I know I still do this, even if it appears unnecessary to me at this point.

It’s also possible your tube is slightly large for a 23mm tire, especially if the bike previously had 25mm tires. The tube would still be usable, but you may need to be a bit more careful when mounting.

Last, it may be worth mentioning that it’s been shown that narrower tires are less comfortable than wider ones, and they provide no advantage in rolling resistance. Additionally, I suspect that manufacturers may gradually kill off 23mm tires, as fewer cyclists will need them. But anyway, what you have will fit the rim.

Comment: Thank You for the quick response.  Since I am uncertain whether my issue is Wheel, tube, Tire or a Rider Issue, I referred to the “25-28 - 622" road wheel” because this is clearly displayed on the rubber spoke protector around the circumference of the wheel... I believed this to be the actual wheel size, and possibly NOT.  I have a photo, and don't see a way to upload it.    You best news is the first and last sentence which indicate what I have is OK and narrows my issue down to a Tube that might be too large or a Rider's installation issue.  I'll check.